# How do I count up to a certain number in jQuery given a pre-defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined a variable in a function which stores a value provided by a 'data' attribute in a  tag.

I.e. `<img data-value="##"/>` (## denoting a number from 1 - XX).

I have stored this variable as such:

```
$dataValue = $('img').attr('data-value');
```

I now want to use `$dataValue` variable to append all `<img>` tags with all the values. For example, given the data-value is 4, the output would be:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=1" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=2" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=3" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=4" />
```

I have done the below so far, but I am not able to figure out a way to increment over the number '4' (or whatever number the data-value is) and spit out 4 image tags in incremental order as shown above.

```
var img = '<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=' + $dataValue + '" />';

// <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=4" />
```

How do I achieve the output above so that all numbers starting from 1 are logged up till the data-value number. I want to use these to then append these  tags to another place.

Comment: Would a for loop not suffice?

Comment: use a for loop from 1 to the `data-value` value and use the loop value to achieve what you want, see my answer below

Comment: Use `.data('value)` to get the attribute from the element as it will then be an int and you won't need to convert its type before you loop, as described above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) is all you need

```
var dataValue = $('img').data('value');
for (i = 1; i <= dataValue; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50?text=' + dataValue + '" />')
}
```

Where `$('.container')` is the name of the element you want to append the images.

Also, I suggest you get the dataValue using `.data()` instead of `.attr()` as [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) is made just for that.

Also keep in mind that `.append()` can be changed for other methods such as `.before()`, `.after()`, `.prepend()`, etc. I suggest you read up on the method you need.

Comment: OP wants to go from 1 to the value, your answer will take him from 0 to value -1.

Comment: True. Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @VVV - Thanks, actually managed to solve it myself in the end but this is good for reference! .data() is the one !

Comment: @VVV - I have managed to make this work when the page is loaded with the initial data. But say for instance, i click a button to 'load more' data, this doesn't work. do you have any suggestions on would i make it compatible with that?

Comment: @zxync you'll need to wrap the code in a function. Then call the function on page load, and when the button is clicked.